# Resources usage in dedicated server issue

Tags: technical-issues, counter-strike-source

I'm trying to make a Counter Strike:Source server with following properties:

- Maximum players: 15
- CSSMath plugin
- Fully voice enabled

With the above properties, how much resources (Bandwidth, RAM, CPU, etc) are needed? and how can I calculate the resources needed?

Answer (score 1):

It's [hard to determine the resources for Bandwidth](http://whisper.ausgamers.com/wiki/index.php/Tickrate#Server_Bandwidth_Calculation_for_Dummies) as you're going to have players joining and dropping at random intervals.

> For a single TF2 server running 24 players, expect to need at least a 2.4GHz processor (AMD or newer-generation Intel, old Intels like P4s won't be fast enough), and 1GB of RAM.

--[TheMG at SteamPowered Forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=689702) (*link also contains original source for bandwidth calculation.*)

TF2 is relevant because it is essentially the same engine running. I don't know much about the CSSMath plugin, so you're on your own there but from the experience I have with servers and plugins, it shouldn't be too taxing.